# How to use GROUP BY which takes into account two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a message table like this in MySQL.

```
   +--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
    +--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
    | id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
    | subject            | varchar(120) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | body               | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
    | sent_at            | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
    | recipient_read     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
    | recipient_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
    | sender_id          | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
    | thread_id          | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
    +--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Messages in a recepient's inbox are to be grouped by `thread_id`  like this:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE recipient_id=42  GROUP BY thread_id ORDER BY sent_at DESC
```

My problem is how to take `recipient_read` into account so that each row in the result also show what is the `recipient_read` value of the last message in the thread?

Comment: I think you want `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I already use `ORDER BY`. Will you pelase elaborate?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: In common use, and you can easily verify this by simply doing a bit of googling, Fields and columns are the same thing. (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65609/column-vs-field-have-i-been-using-these-terms-incorrectly )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original query, the `ORDER BY` is only satisfied *after* the `GROUP BY` operation. The `ORDER BY` affects the order of the returned rows. It does not influence which rows are returned.

With the non-aggregate expression in the SELECT list, it is indeterminate *which* values will be returned; the value of each column will be from *some* row in the collapsed group. But it's not guaranteed to be the first row, or the latest row, or any other specific row.  The behavior of MySQL (allowing the query to run without throwing an error) is enabled by a MySQL extension.

Other relational databases would throw a "non-aggregate in SELECT list not in GROUP BY" type error with the query.  MySQL exhibits a similar (standard) behavior when `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is included in `sql_mode` system variable.  MySQL allows the original query to run (and return unexpected results) because of a non-standard, MySQL-specific extension.

The pattern of the original query is essentially broken.

---

To get a resultset that satisfies the specification, we can write a query to get the latest (maximum) `sent_at` datetime for each `thread_id`, for a given set of `recipient_id` (in the example query, the set is a single `recipient_id`.)

```
SELECT lm.recipient_id
     , lm.thread_id
     , MAX(lm.sent_at) AS latest_sent_at
  FROM message lm
 WHERE lm.recipient_id = 42
 GROUP
    BY lm.recipient_id
     , lm.thread_id
```

We can use the result from that query in another query, by making in an inline view (wrap it in parens, and reference it in the FROM clause like table, assign an alias).

We can join that resultset to the original table to retrieve all of the columns from the rows that match.

Something like this:

```
SELECT m.id
     , m.subject
     , m.body
     , m.sent_at
     , m.recipient_read
     , m.recipient_id
     , m.sender_id
     , m.thread_id
  FROM (
         SELECT lm.recipient_id
              , lm.thread_id
              , MAX(lm.sent_at) AS latest_sent_at
           FROM message lm
          WHERE lm.recipient_id = 42
          GROUP
             BY lm.recipient_id
              , lm.thread_id
       ) l
  JOIN message m
    ON m.recipient_id = l.recipient_id
   AND m.thread_id    = l.thread_id
   AND m.sent_at      = l.latest_sent_at
 ORDER
    BY ...
```

Note that if `(recipient_id,thread_id,sent_at)` is not guaranteed to be unique, there is a potential that there will be multiple rows with the same "maximum" `sent_at`; that is, we could get more than one row back for a given maximum `sent_at`.

We can order that result however we want, with whatever expressions. That will affect only the order that the rows are returned in, not which rows are returned.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the informative answer. It solved my problem and added to my knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last message, you want filtering, not aggregation:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message m
WHERE m.recipient_id = 42 AND
      m.sent_at = (SELECT MAX(m2.sent_at)
                   FROM messages m2
                   WHERE m2.thread_id = m.thread_id
                  )
ORDER BY m.sent_at DESC;
```